# How to merge multiple packs of flaticons into one pack?

Tags: web, icons

I am using [Flaticons](http://www.flaticon.com/) for my website. Mostly I am collecting icons from 3 to 4 packs. I would like to know, if there is any possibility to merge multiple packs from [Flaticons](http://www.flaticon.com/) into one new pack. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I think this is a good question. I've downloaded some fonts as well, and find it weird that they're named the same. Makes it hard to implement, unless there is some smart way to combine them?

Answer (score 0):

You could this website

```
https://icomoon.io/
```

it has the ability of merging multiple svg packs just import the packs into the website and you could export them into one pack

Answer (score 0):

open `flaticon.css` and change `font-family` to something else, for example, in this case, I changed to `Flaticon2`. then, note that css class names must be Unicode. in this case i changes all class names to start with `.flaticon2`

this is my `flaticon.css`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon2"; /* <<< NOTE */
  src: url("./Flaticon.eot");
  src: url("./Flaticon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
       url("./Flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
       url("./Flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
       url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Flaticon2"; /* <<< NOTE */
    src: url("./Flaticon.svg#Flaticon") format("svg");
  }
}

[class^="flaticon2-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon2-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon2-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon2-"]:after {   
  font-family: Flaticon2;
        font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.flaticon2-001-cloudy:before { content: "\f100"; }
.flaticon2-002-wallet:before { content: "\f101"; }
.flaticon2-003-trekking:before { content: "\f102"; }
.flaticon2-004-travel:before { content: "\f103"; }
.flaticon2-005-train:before { content: "\f104"; }
.flaticon2-006-tourist:before { content: "\f105"; }
.flaticon2-007-ticket:before { content: "\f106"; }
.flaticon2-008-taxi:before { content: "\f107"; }
.flaticon2-009-sunset:before { content: "\f108"; }
.flaticon2-010-sunglasses:before { content: "\f109";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace all "Flaticon" string to "Flaticon-yourName" in one of the CSS file.

Comment: Can I use Flations for iPhone [ swift base ] project ?

Comment: I have no experience at the top of IPhone project with Flations.

Comment: I didi it, via importing .ttf file in my project, thanks :)